# I need to find the source of some data on an ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to locate how some external data is being passed into our website, I don't have any experience with ASP but know C# pretty well. I have narrowed the search down to a line in the page displaying the data I need to find the source of:

```
<DI:FAF runat='server' PredefinedCategory='Australian Sites' />
```

I am guessing the DI stands for dependency injection, but from there I'm stumped. Can anyone point me towards the code this command calls?

Comment: First, it's not ASP.NET MVC, this is a WebForms control. `DI` is the namespace of this control and `FAF` is the control name. If you are saying "data is being passed" to your website, I assume `DI:FAF` renders some HTML form inputs which values are then captured by the control during a postback.

Comment: It seems DI is a tag prefix for a Server Control created by someone in your team. It doesn't seem to be a third party control to me. And, this must be defined in one of the configuration files in your project. Do a search in Entire solution to find that out.

Comment: At the top of your page you will have a line like `<%@ Register Src="~somepath.ascx" TagPrefix="DI" TagName="FAF" %>`.  That will give you the path to your code.  Additionally as @AndréPena says, this is webforms, not mvc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help dudes, found!

Answer (score 0):

It seems DI is a tag prefix for a Server Control created by someone in your team. It doesn't seem to be a third party control to me. And, this must be defined in one of the configuration files in your project. Do a search in Entire solution to find that out.